# Problems with tbb in native dll called from multi-threaded .net application?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, clr, tbb

We have a native .dll that does some HPC type calculations using Threading Building Blocks 4.4 to manage parallelism.  This .dll is called from a .Net desktop program that is itself multi-threaded.  I'm a novice at tbb, and I was wondering if this kind of set-up was inviting some issues.  My use of tbb is pretty basic-- I'm just calling parallel_reduce to do one particular calculation.  I'm not explicitly setting up the tbb threadpool; I'm relying on the default initialization for that.

When we do system tests we are seeing some intermittent process hangs.  We are not seeing these when we test the native dll in isolation, so I expect a minimal example that demonstrates the problem would be difficult to construct.  I'm hoping someone more familiar with tbb than I might be able to suggest if there is likely to be an intrinsic problem in this usage scenario.

Everything is running on Windows 10 on x86-64 platform, by the way.

Comment: How do you observe "intermittent process hangs". Is the GUI refreshed with delays? Does the whole system become unresponsive? Could not it be caused by high CPU utilization and oversubscription?

Comment: @Alex - Two behaviors: 1, GUI becomes unresponsive with no CPU activity.  2, GUI shuts down as if it crashed, but there is no "This application has encountered an error" dialog.

Comment: Could not memory errors in native code (e.g. due to incorrect marshaling or something else) lead to unstable behavior of the managed runtime? Have you tried to run parallel_reduce with empty Body?

Comment: @Alex - thanks for the suggestion.  It  turns out the problem was purely on the managed side; TBB didn't have any role at all, did just what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question appears to be that there is no problem; Threading Building Blocks can work fine in this scenario.  Eliminating the parallel_reduce didn't change the behavior, and further investigation shows that the problem was confined to the managed code; didn't have anything to do with TBB at all.